# Disable Custom Admin URL

Tags: magento2, custom-admin-url

I'm new with magento. I'm accidentally changed **Use Custom Admin URL** value into **Yes** and added a **custom admin url** (which is doesn't exist). Now everytime i tried to access my magento admin it always redirect to that **custom admin url** and gives error because that URL doesn't exist. I have tried to return it to **No** and click save but i always get **webadmin-sit-ecomm.tbsgroup.co.id’s server IP address could not be found.**

[image]
I have also tried to change it from the **core_config_data** table but still the same. All I need to do is return **Use Custom Admin URL** value to **No**. Can Anyone please help?
[image]

Comment: GoTo Magento root directory and run bin/magento cache:flush. Then try again to access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento will add more rows than we think. Try to delete custom admin rows and new custom url values. Remember to flush the Magento cache. Your admin will be back.

[image]

My Magento version is 2.3.1.

Comment: So it's okay to delete those rows?

Comment: Backup your database first. And, delete these rows then.

Comment: I have deleted rows that contain admin url and flush magento cache but my admin page still redirect to the webpage that doesn't exists.

Comment: Did you try to delete `admin/url/custom, admin/url/use_custom, admin/url/use_custom_path`?

Comment: yes, i deleted those rows.

Comment: How many stores in your site?

Comment: we have one store

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104015/discussion-between-khoa-truongdinh-and-wira-xie).

Answer (score 0):

Try to add as custom url , the full admin url you want :

> UPDATE `core_config_data` SET value = 'Enter you admin url here' WHERE
>   path = 'admin/url/custom';

Run

```
bin/magento cache:clean && bin/magento cache:flush
bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Answer (score 0):

Execute this command to revert to the default Admin URL

**

> php bin/magento config:set admin/url/use_custom 0

**
Execute this command to revert to the default Admin Path (set in the app/etc/env.php as described in the Method 2)

> php bin/magento config:set admin/url/use_custom_path 0

Use one of the following methods to clear the Magento cache:

On the Admin sidebar, go to System > Tools > Cache Management. Then, click Flush Magento Cache.
On the server, execute the following:

> php bin/magento cache:flush